# How can I use dbt with clickhouse?

Tags: clickhouse, dbt

Does anyone use dbt with clickhouse database and how do you do this?

I see that there is no native support, maybe you use some packages?

Answer (score 3):

There isn't currently a way to use dbt with ClickHouse. The databases that [dbt supports](https://docs.getdbt.com/docs/supported-databases/) are Postgres, Snowflake, BigQuery and Redshift, with partial support for Presto and Spark.

If you wanted dbt to work with ClickHouse, the best path forward would be to create your own dbt adapter. You can see [here](https://docs.getdbt.com/docs/contributing/building-a-new-adapter/) the steps required for doing so.

It is possible that, in time, ClickHouse could become supported by the dbt maintainers or that a community member build a community-supported adapter that you could use.

Comment: Note there is now a plugin available https://github.com/silentsokolov/dbt-clickhouse